# how use ckeditor full version in react component

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using the react-ckeditor in project this is load ok.
but I need to use ckeditor full version as editor in the page

how could I use react-ckeditor full version not the standard version?

Comment: what happened when you tried to follow [the documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html)? what was the error message?

Comment: I didn't get any error and every thing is fine and ckeditor tools is standard and I need the full version not the standard version

Comment: there are no "standard" or "full" versions in https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/download/

Comment: i need full package as react component [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_react.html#customizing-ckeditor-preset-or-version):

> By default, the CKEditor 4 React component loads the standard preset of the latest CKEditor 4 release from the CDN when creating the first editor. This behavior can be altered by changing the value of the CKEditor.editorUrl variable to point to the desired CKEditor script location:
>
> ```
> CKEditor.editorUrl = 'https://your-website.example/ckeditor/ckeditor.js';
> ```

A zip file can be downloaded from https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/ and upzipped inside your source code (e.g. inside `public/ckeditor-4` folder if using create-react app).

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue as I wanted to include all the available options in my toolbar. Turns out all you need to do is mention the type of **distribution** in your CDN link as **full-all**, to include full preset together with all other plugins created by CKSource.

I changed it from standard to full-all in my CDN link as given below-

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.0/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Also, check the version. This is my source of info: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/

Hope this helps :)